# Cannot read Json value by key in JenkinsFile

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am defining my environment variables in Jenkins-File.
I am using Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin to read a json file in the directory that has configuration.
When I echo out the read json file, the output is correct, it reads and prints the json file correctly.
When I try to access the value associated with a key in that json object, I am getting error: "***No such property: internalCentralConsoleUrl for class: java.lang.String***"

The json format config file looks life following:

```
{
    "activeVersion": "19.01.303",
    "internalCentralConsoleUrl": "https://11.111.111:8083/api/v1",
    "dataType": "APPLICATION_JSON"
}
```

I am reading that file using readJSON in the pipeline.
And in the following lines, trying to access the value inside the json object using the key.
Which gives the error I mentioned above.

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment { 
        config = readJSON file: 'config.json'
        baseUrl = "${config.internalCentralConsoleUrl}"
        baseUrl2 = config['internalCentralConsoleUrl']
        }
stages {}
}
```

Both the ways I tried above to read the json value are documented in the jenkins page linked [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)

I cannot wrap my head around what is causing an issue in this straight forward task.

Edit1: Just corrected a formatting mistake in pipeline.

Comment: Try the relative path: `config = readJSON file: './config.json'`.

Comment: There is no problem reading the file itself. The problem is getting value from the json object that is available after reading the json file.

Comment: I do not believe you can do this within the `environment` block. Is there any reason you want to do it there?

Comment: I am just trying to get all the environment level dependencies resolved in the environment block. And some frequently required values available in variables so they are easy to access.

Answer (score 5):

I copied your example and added a stage to print the variable:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def config = readJSON file: 'config.json'
        baseUrl = "${config.internalCentralConsoleUrl}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo baseUrl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it prints the variable correctly without any exception:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
https://11.111.111:8083/api/v1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: Thank you, for doing this, I think the issue might be with my 1. Jenkins Host, 2. Jenkins itself, 3. The plugin. I will look into those.

Answer (score 1):

After [RNoB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8997124/rnob)'s comment above that it works fine in his Jenkins; I came to the conclusion that it has nothing to do with the pipeline and it might be:
a. Jenkins Plugin issue.
b. Jenkins itself.
c. Host where Jenkins is running.

So, I took the following approach:
a. I upgraded the plugins, and reinstalled them. This did not fix the problem.
b. I uninstalled Jenkins and removed all Jenkins related files and reinstalled it, and installed all the plugins again. This fixed the problem.

I still don't know what exactly was wrong, it just might be some file that was corrupt. I am not Jenkins expert but this solved the issue for me. Hope this will be helpful for somebody who is having similar issue.